# URL fetch request size in googleaapengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt2, urlfetch

I am doing a web application project using GWT in Eclipse.

I have a file on the client side which is to send on the project.server and from server to external Repository.

```
    File
     |
     V
  Client-->Server-->Repository
```

Iam Using  default SDk - `(appengine-java-sdk-1.6.3.1- 1.6.3)`

```
GWT-2.4.0
```

according to documentation [googleappengine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes)  , the limit for URL fetch request is `5Mb`.

** But I cannot fetch the request more then 3.8Mb **

If i try to fetch more then 3.8 Mb then it gives me an Error.

```
   Cannot access http://URL: The request to API call urlfetch.Fetch() was too large.
```

Can somebody explain me the reason for this.

Even i have to download the file from repository and save it on client side.

So is there any limitaion of size to getContent of the file present in the Repository to the server Side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a binary file being sent over HTTP, it's probably being encoded as base64 before being transfered.  That adds about 33% to the file size.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64